# publishing a svelte 3 component: semantics for "main" and "svelte" fields of package.json?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I took the Svelte tutorial and rewrote the keypad in the [`component bindings`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings) section with a state machine. That [worked lovely](https://brucou.github.io/documentation/v1/examples/keypad.html).

Now I want to extract the `Machine.svelte` file into a `npm` package and I am not sure how to do that. I could not find any documentation about publishing. For what I saw from [svelte-virtual-list](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-virtual-list), I probably have to configure either the `main` or `svelte` field of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@sveltejs/svelte-virtual-list",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "A <VirtualList> component for Svelte apps",
  "main": "VirtualList.svelte",
  "svelte": "VirtualList.svelte",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -cw",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm test",
    "test": "node test/runner.js",
    "test:browser": "npm run build && serve test/public",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "lint": "eslint src/VirtualList.svelte"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "git+https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3.git",
    "port-authority": "^1.0.5",
    "puppeteer": "^1.9.0",
    "rollup": "^1.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.1",
    "sirv": "^0.2.2",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "tap-diff": "^0.1.1",
    "tap-dot": "^2.0.0",
    "tape-modern": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-virtual-list",
  "author": "Rich Harris",
  "license": "LIL",
  "keywords": [
    "svelte"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src",
    "index.mjs",
    "index.js"
  ]
}
```

Is that a correct assumption? Additionally I am perplexed by the fact that in the `package.json.files` the `VirtualList.svelte` is not present? How would you go about publishing a svelte component??

EDIT: [final gist](https://svelte.dev/repl/baf4a28592ff4723bb0947163ee1f109?version=3.5.3) correctly importing the `Machine` Svelte component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `svelte` field is used by [rollup-plugin-svelte](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-svelte) and (if properly configured) [svelte-loader](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-loader) to locate the source file, so that your third party components get compiled at the same time as the rest of your app (and import from the same internal library).

In a case like svelte-virtual-list, where you can't really use it programmatically from JavaScript (i.e. it has to be inside another component), there's really no point having a `main` field as well; that's something left over from a previous version I think.

But in some cases you *do* want non-Svelte-users to be able to use your component as a standalone class, and that's when `main` is useful, as long as it points to a precompiled JavaScript file. This could be generated with rollup-plugin-svelte during a `prepublish` script (though we could do a better job of generating some standard workflows around this). For maximum compatibility, a component — or package of components — intended to be used in this way should have a `pkg.main` (usually `index.js` which is a CommonJS or UMD file), and a `pkg.module` (usually `index.mjs` which is a JavaScript module).

> Additionally I am perplexed by the fact that in the package.json.files the VirtualList.svelte is not present?

Regardless of what's in `pkg.files`, `pkg.main` will *always* be included. Since there's an erroneous `pkg.main` in svelte-virtual-list, the `VirtualList.svelte` file is included in the package even though I forgot to add it to `pkg.files`.